# how to remove space between authors initials when using the apalike bibliography style

Tags: spacing, bibtex, apa-style

Suppose my reference looks like the one below:

Author, J. M. (2006). Comparing species abundance models. Ecological Modelling,
199(2):153 – 163.

How to remove space between the two initials of the author, so that I obtain Last, J.M.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a copy of `apalike.bst` and name it something useful like `apalike-nospace.bst`.  Save this in your local `texmf` folder in `texmf/bib/bst`.

Then change the `format.names` function in the `.bst` file.
 The crucial change is in the following string in the function which tells `bibtex` how to format the name pieces:

```
"{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}"
```

This needs to be changed to:

```
"{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}"
```

The `f` part is the initials part, and the default inter-element unit is a space. We need to override that explicitly by using  `{.}` instead.

Here's the whole function with old and new versions:

#### Original code:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't :=   % last name first
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

#### New code

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f{.}.}" format.name$ 't :=   % last name first
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you, Alan. I was close, but I would never guess to add {.}