# write name of author in BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies

I want to write the following in BibTeX as the author name:

> S.H. Wilf

i.e. there was no space between the two letters "S" and "H".

Comment: bibtex as in title or biblatex as in tag? Please show full MWE.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to give the initials in your `.bib` file, you can write

```
author = {Wilf, S. H.},
```

or

```
author = {S. H. Wilf},
```

If you write `author = {Wilf, S.H.},` BibTeX will not be able to tell that "S.H." is two initials and will abbreviate the name to "S. Wilf" if asked to abbreviate names.

Note that the style you use controls the output and decides whether or not this comes out as

> S. H. Wilf

or

> S.H. Wilf

or even

> SH Wilf

more or less independent of the (correct) input.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{wilf,
  author = {Wilf, S. H.},
  title  = {Lorem},
  year   = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{wilf}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

If you want your BibTeX style to produce initials without spaces, you would normally try to modify your `.bst` file to use the name format `{f{.}.~}` for first names, see for example [how to remove space between authors initials when using the apalike bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257910/35864). But this can mess up hyphens as explained in Q35 of [`btxFAQ`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/btxFAQ.pdf).

With `biblatex` this is as easy as redefining `\bibinitdelim` and hyphenated names shouldn't be messed up.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, giveninits, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{wilf,
  author = {Wilf, S. H.},
  title  = {Lorem},
  year   = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{wilf}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating your `.bib` document, you can format the authors as follows:

```
author = {Surname, Name}
```

which, in your case, can be formatted as

```
author = {Wilf, S.H.}
```